# Drupalgap: Hello World sample - where is app folder?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a Drupal 7 website and wish to develop a mobile app for it. I have successfully installed Drupalgap. I am trying to run the Hello World sample app described in the Drupalgap 7 docs. The instructions say to create a custom module and place it in the `app/modules/custom/my_module` folder. The problem is that I don't have an "app" folder anywhere. What am I missing?
Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Substitute "app" for "/path/to/Drupal" - it just represents the root of your Drupal installation

Comment: Go to the Mobile-application folder in your setup  and check the folders.

Comment: @Clive, the `app` folder is typically located within the "mobile-application" directory, not the Drupal root, so a typical path to the app folder would be `/var/www/[drupal-root]/mobile-application/app`

Answer (score 2):

The app folder is in the folder mobile-application

1. Root folder drupal

   - mobile-application
   - - app
   - - - modules
   - - - - custom
   - - - - - my_module

[image: Drupalgap folder structure]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the admin/config/services/drupalgap. In this mobile-application is the folder where your app is running.

[image]

2. Go to the drupal project folder.
   "var/www/html/drupal/mobile-application" In this directory app folder is exist

Answer (score 0):

If you have not change anything and go to the DrupalGap module configuration and installed the SDK then you will get the app folder in root inside mobile-application folder.

[image]